# Ionic custom button animation triggers on all buttons

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, css-animations

I am trying to implement an animated favourite button in an Ionic app and I'm having a few issues.

The button is working as expected on click, but it is also triggering every other button to play the animation. The animation also plays on all buttons every time the page loads. I suspect that my ngClass statement for adding the active class is somehow being triggered when the page loads the posts and again when the data is updated from the observable when a favourite is added.

```
<ion-button class="favourite" fill="clear" size="small" (click)="toggleFavourite( post, user.userId )">
   <ion-icon [ngClass]="{'active': post.favourites && post.favourites[user.userId] ? true : false}" class="heart"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

css:

```
.heart {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
    background: url('/assets/images/heart.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    animation: fave-heart 1s steps(28);
}

.heart.active {
    background-position: -2800px 0;
    transition: background 1s steps(28);
}

@keyframes fave-heart {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: -2800px 0;
    }
}
```

I have done some more testing and found that the button animation is triggered every time I update my posts variable. The posts are returned as an observable so it is updated whenever the page loads and also when a user favourites a post so I can update the button. However, I added a button which calls the getPosts() function (below) and it also triggers the animation on each click.

```
<ion-button (click)="getPosts(limit)">click</ion-button>

getPosts(limit){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.postsService.getPosts(limit).subscribe(data => {
        this.posts = data.reverse()
        let key = data[data.length - 1].$key;
        if (this.lastId === key){
          this.hasMoreData = false;
        }
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: maybe because you dont put the animation in the .active in your css ?

Comment: It does seem to be working, its just that the animation happens on every button. The button that was clicked finishes the animation and ends on a solid heart as expected. The rest of the buttons animate and then return to the heart outline.

Comment: you could use the `.heart:active` instead. No javascript required

Comment: I can't use :active as I need to change the class so that when posts are loaded I can change the button state based on if it has been favourited or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some more research and found a much better way of doing it. This way uses Ionic 5 animations so I can target the id of the element that has been clicked to play the animation when I choose.

```
&.heart {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   transform: scale(0.9);
   background: url('/assets/images/heart.png') no-repeat;
   background-position: 0 0;
   cursor: pointer;
}
&.heart.active {
   background-position: -2800px 0;
}
```

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let post of postList ; let i = index;">
   <ion-button (click)="toggleFavourite( post, user.userId, '#favourite' + i )">
      <ion-icon [id]="'favourite'+i" class="heart" color="pink" [ngClass]="{'active': post.favourites && post.favourites[user.userId] ? true : false}"></ion-icon>
   </ion-button>
</ion-col>
```

```
import { AnimationController } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(private animationCtrl: AnimationController){ }

animateForward(elementId){
    const animation = this.animationCtrl
      .create()
      .addElement(document.querySelector(elementId))
      .duration(1000)
      .iterations(1)
      .easing( 'steps(28, end)')
      .keyframes([
        { offset: 0, backgroundPosition: '0 0' },
        { offset: 1, backgroundPosition: '-2800px 0' }
      ])

    animation.play()
  }

  animateBack(elementId){
    const animation = this.animationCtrl
      .create()
      .addElement(document.querySelector(elementId))
      .duration(300)
      .iterations(1)
      .easing( 'steps(28, end)')
      .keyframes([
        { offset: 0, transform: 'scale(0.9)' },
        { offset: 0.7, transform: 'scale(1)' },
        { offset: 1, transform: 'scale(0.9)' }
      ])

    animation.play()
  }
```